# How to mutiply the result of the pow function before the modulus in Python

Tags: python, encryption, pow

I want to perform the following calculation in Python:

`h^r * m  mod p`

All of the variables in this calculation are extremely large numbers.  This formula would work if the numbers weren't as large:

`c2 = (pow(pk,r) * m) % p`

But because the numbers are so large, this makes my machine hang. So the natural solution is to include the third argument of the `pow` function to include the modulus in that calculation.  This calculates extremely fast:

`pow(pk,r,p)`

^ But how can I adapt this formula above to multiply the result of `pk^r` by `m` before the modulus is accounted for?

Comment: Just use `(pow(pk, r, p) * m) % p`.  You get the same results.  I don't know of any good shortcut.

Comment: @FrankYellin could you explain how you get the same result even though you are taking the modulus of p twice?

Comment: Math.  Modular arithmetic is a ring.   If I'm calculating `(pk * pk * pk * pk * ..... * pk * m) % p`, then I can take the modulus as few or as many times as I want when doing the multiplications, as long as I do a final modulus at the end; I'll always get the same result.  The python function `pow(pk, r, p)` doesn't calculate `pk ** r` and then take the modulus; it does repeating squaring and a modulus operation after every step.

Comment: @FrankYellin I really appreciate the help. Using this same logic, what expression would you use to calculate ```h / r^m  mod p```

Comment: If you're using a new enough version of Python, then it accepts a negative modulus.  So you're trying to calculate `r^(-m) * h (mod p)`.  So it's the exact same thing as before, but -m instead of m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70825819/1820553) is not correct. It is missing one important part; dividing `exp` by 2;

```
base = 4
exp = 12
mod = 7
m = 8
result = 1
while exp>0:
    if exp%2==0:
        result = (result*base)%mod
    base = (base*base)%mod
    exp = exp //2
print((m*result)%mod)
```

When  `exp = exp //2` is missing, it will run forever since `exp>0` will be correct forever.

We don't advise writing a function yourself if it is in the library. There is already one in Python ( actually the one that you have uses with [an optional third parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_pow.asp));

```
pow(base, exp, mod)
```

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| base | A number the base |
| exp | A number, the exponent |
| mod | Optional. A number, the modulus |

This library already handling this for you with the Montgomery Modular Multiplication technique that is better than standard repeating squaring if the power is not small.

```
pow(base, exp, mod) * m % mod
```

Just use it.

Since this is about encryption, we must also say that one needs a [secure modular exponentiation against side-channel](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75408/18298) attacks. GNU/GMP has already [mpz_powm_sec](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation) for this purposes. You can access this with [gmpy2](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/) module.

Comment: I forgot that line, I corrected it but you could've put a comment to tell me. Thanks for correcting me anyway

Comment: Well, actually, I wrote this for the last part. This talks about encryption then one must use a secure one.

Comment: Ok, its interesting to read anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following algorithm, where you multiply the base by itself when the exponent is odd.
 Then you know it's even and you can divide it by 2, and multiply the base by itself.
You do that because it divides by 2 the number of calculations.
Example below:

```
base = 4
exp = 12
mod = 7
m = 8
result = 1
while exp>0:
    if exp%2==0:
        result = (result*base)%mod
    base = (base*base)%mod
    exp = exp//2
print((m*result)%mod)
```

Or you can use the third parameter in the pow function Like this: `(pow(base, exp, mod)*m)%mod`

Comment: I'm going to strongly recommend that you just use `pow(base, exp, mod) * m % mod` as I suggested above, and not use this code.  This code is just a roll-your-own implementation of `pow(base, exp, mod). ` 

The Python implementation of `pow` with a large modulus uses Montgomery reduction, which is much faster than the simple repeated squaring algorithm.

Comment: @FrankYellin thank you Frank. I tried to use the code above and it stalled out my machine.  Your suggestion works better

Comment: @oryan5000 because the code is not correct. See my answer...